# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function error only in build version

Tags: reactjs, types, react-hooks, use-state

I get this error only in my build version of project, in production it does not cause any errors

```
TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
```

and it refers to this line of code in

```
const [searchedVal, setSearchedVal] = useState("");
```

and only time I have used setSearchedVal is when getting a value from a input onChange

```
  const onChange = (e) => {
    setSearchedVal(e.target.value);
  };
```

how to fix this
thanks,

Comment: Can you post the entire code please, it shouldn't refer to `setSearchedVal`

Comment: @SinanYaman its just a very long component like 700 lines, but can you explain the error, does it mean Im using a object as a function ? and why is it only occurring in build version not production

Comment: Hey, can you share a link to this repo?

Comment: @JevonCochran oh this was a long time ago, the problem was useEffect was imported from react/cjs/react.development, which causes weird errors in production, vs code sometimes auto imports from there, so gotta be careful about that and check where ur stuff are imported from;)